# Proxify all the traffic from B to A

Tags: iptables, proxy

My computer A has two networks, one connects to internet. The other one connects to computer B. How can I setup A to route all the internet traffic from B through a proxy running on A without setting B too much, possibly acting like a transparent proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use A as gateway. Enable IP forwarding on machine A and configure it NAT outgoing traffic.

Quick overview:

1. Configure addresses interfaces connecting A and B on (both hosts). Verify by pinging between both hosts using these addresses.
2. Enable routing:

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

   (also check there are no limiting rules in `FORWARD` chain of `filter` table)
3. Add NAT rules on host A (assuming `eth0` connects to internet):

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
4. Configure DNS on host B.

Comment: Not whole computer A is a proxy, just a software running on A provides the proxy, so there should be a proxy address and port somewhere in iptables when routing traffic into a proxy?

Comment: Then you should them mention what proxy software/protocol you are using/want to use. When you configure Linux to do IP forwarding (and NATting) the Linux kernel is the software implementing routing.